# Best way to pass a PHP array to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I wondering what the appropriate way is to bring in an array created in PHP and make it available to JS/jQuery (my front end)?

Dont get me wrong.. it 'works'..as far as functionality.. but I have a HUGE openly defined (multi-dimensional, object array) displayed in the source code...etc  Nature of the beast? or a better/different way?

quick example

```
<?php
    $totalEntries = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $totalEntriesArray2 = json_encode($totalEntriesArray);
?>
<script>
    var totalEntriesArray  = <?= $totalEntriesArray2 ?>;
</script>
```

this works. I access the array as intended (multi-dimensional, object array..etc)

Is there a better/cleaner/simpler way similar to above?

Comment: Simpler than what you have? What is wrong with what you have? I don't see a huge openly defined object array here. Show the problematic code, not the code that is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose using an Ajax request on the frontend that fetches the JSON array whenever the page is loaded.

A simple way of doing it would be via jQuery.

Backend PHP file (getarray.php) :

```
<?php

$totalEntries = mysql_num_rows($result);
totalEntriesArray2 = json_encode($totalEntriesArray);

echo $totalEntriesArray2;

?>
```

Frontend Javascript file (either in page or seperate .js file) :

```
// Execute Ajax request
$.ajax({url: "/getarray.php", dataType: "json"})

// When complete do something with data
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This is a good methodology, but if the data is not dynamic, I would recommend you use the way you are doing it originally in your question to save on some extra http calls as it would be faster.

Comment: the whole page is already dynamic; it's going through php.  there's absolutely no point in doing a second request here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array using AJAX in jQuery, so you won't have this array shown in your source code.